# im getting 'local gulp not found' in an old angularjs code despite doing npm install and also installing gulp packages

Tags: angularjs, gulp, node-sass, gyp

Ive been provided an old Angularjs code by my senior developer and i am told to build and run it in my laptop. but i tried npm install --save-dev . the code contains a gulp file also , and it had a gitlab.yml file that instructed me to use commands after npm install such as gulp clean and gulp build . but im getting several errors after installing the packages like :

- deprecation errors and consider upgrading it to this .
- gyp errors (which i have no clue about)

and also while running those gulp commands it says 'local gulp not found ' in my specific project directory , despite trying to install gulp before .

i tried a lots of ways to resolve this error , i couldnt even update the outdated packages . the same amount of errors are being thrown and it persists again and again repeatedly.